# How to use pandas to filter and create a new column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to filter through 3 columns of a dataframe and have conditions for the 3 columns and return a binary value say 1 if all conditions are met and 0 if the conditions are not met. An example is show below.

```
data = {'PassengerId': array([2255, 2257, 2258, 2256, 2257, 2258, 2255, 2258, 2257, 2257, 2255,
        2255, 2257, 2256, 2257, 2256, 2255, 2258, 2258, 2256, 2256, 2257,
        2258, 2258, 2257]),
 'Pclass': array([3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3,
        1, 1, 2]),
 'Age': array([40, 33, 32, 40, 48, 24, 33, 29, 29, 31, 45, 47, 28, 32, 54, 39, 28,
        50, 40, 31, 51, 26, 41, 46, 27]),
 'SibSp': array([11, 13, 12, 19, 22, 17, 23, 12, 12, 12, 12, 24, 16, 21, 12, 15, 20,
        18, 10, 17, 20, 12, 17, 17, 10]),
 'Comf' : array([236.66883531, 235.46750709, 235.64574546, 241.16838089,
        239.40728836, 239.95592634, 236.67806901, 237.73350635,
        238.74497849, 235.17486552, 235.8457374 , 236.85133744,
        240.9359547 , 236.27703374, 237.81871052, 241.62788018,
        241.29185342, 235.0058136 , 240.69989317, 238.8073828 ,
        238.08841364, 236.55259788, 237.58108419, 239.66916186,
        241.97479544]),
 'Parch': array([232.37686437, 232.39153096, 230.56566556, 232.77980061,
        232.19436342, 232.2165835 , 232.28145641, 231.26988217,
        230.55287196, 232.26528521, 230.45185855, 230.87525326,
        231.38775744, 232.80960083, 232.33105822, 232.65782351,
        231.64457366, 230.45225829, 231.05404057, 232.38229998,
        232.57354117, 232.08690375, 230.40414215, 230.14361969,
        231.40414745]),
 'Fare': array([238.80427104, 239.32031287, 238.02212358, 238.40333494,
        238.85929097, 239.51666683, 239.87771029, 238.06772515,
        238.22734658, 238.54682118, 238.68880278, 239.79658425,
        238.2642908 , 239.22884058, 239.84423352, 239.69438831,
        238.85871719, 238.64632848, 238.7085097 , 239.5700877 ,
        239.06199698, 238.37341378, 239.16126748, 239.01280153,
        239.77047796])}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

i am trying to have a condition for the first row that if the "Pclass" == 1 and  'Comf' is between "Parch" & "Fare", create a new column 'Survived' and assign 1 else assign 0.

then do the same for "Pclass" == 2, 3...

I would like to do this with pandas, however all solutions to this problem are welcomed.

Comment: What should be the result for PClass 2, 3 .. ? The boolean value if  'Comf' is between "Parch" & "Fare" in the same column "Survived"?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, the result of the PClass 2, 3... Should be 1 if the PClass is == 2, and   'Comf' is between "Parch" & "Fare" assign 1, else 0, then move to the next PClass which is 3, if PClass 3 == 1 and 'Comf' is between "Parch" & "Fare" assign 1, else 0. PS. this is a row operation, the conditions for PClass and Comf is done row-wise.

Comment: I don't understand fully... PClass is just one column. Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it for all rows regardless of PClass value than you can use

```
df["Survived"] = df["Comf"].between(df["Parch"], df["Fare"]).astype(int)
```

but if you want to do for specific PClass than you can use

```
df["Survived"] = (df["Pclass"]==1 & df["Comf"].between(df["Parch"], df["Fare"])).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Steps.

1. Get indexes based on your condition.

`indexesOfTrue = df[(df["Pclass"]==1) & (df["Comf"] > df["Parch"]) & (df["Comf"] < df["Fare"])].index`

2. Fill the indexes using loc.

`df.loc[indexesOfTrue, "Survived"] = 1`

3. Fill untrue indexes.

`df.loc[~df.index.isin(ind), "Survived"] = 0`

**Output**

```
PassengerId  Pclass  Age  SibSp Comf       Parch        Fare  Survived
    5   2258    3   24  17  239.955926  232.216584  239.516667  2
    6   2255    3   33  23  236.678069  232.281456  239.877710  2
    7   2258    4   29  12  237.733506  231.269882  238.067725  2
    8   2257    3   29  12  238.744978  230.552872  238.227347  2
    9   2257    1   31  12  235.174866  232.265285  238.546821  1
    10  2255    1   45  12  235.845737  230.451859  238.688803  1
    11  2255    1   47  24  236.851337  230.875253  239.796584  1
    12  2257    1   28  16  240.935955  231.387757  238.264291  2
    13  2256    2   32  21  236.277034  232.809601  239.228841  2
    14  2257    4   54  12  237.818711  232.331058  239.844234  2
```